# Catch All rule - how to catch all emails that has been sent to not existing email address

Tags: exchange-server, office365

I have a task to create a new rule that must catch all email messages  which will be send to domain with exception - this rule can not concerns existing users.

For example:

I have three users:

user1@domain.com

user2@domain.com

catchall@domain.com

When somebody will send any email message to user3@domain.com, user4@domain.com... all emails send to this addresses will be redirected to catchall@domain.com.

In brief - when somebody send email on address that not exist in this domain, this message will be send to address catchall@domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Transport Rule if you have something like an All Users group that contains all your valid users/groups/etc in the domain. Essentially you will create a transport rule that says "Redirect messages to  if the message is from  except if ". You'll also need to disable the Recipient filtering anti-spam rule.

Generally speaking, though, this is a bad idea. You're creating a mailbox that is going to be absolutely flooded with spam, will take alot of disk space, and will need constant cleanup. Make sure the mailbox has a quota. If you get hit with a deluge of spam, you don't want this mailbox to use up all the disk space on the server and terminate service for your end user community.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872082/7724) doesn't work. That's because

(1) You said you wanted your rule to apply to users who do not already exist
(2) Transport Rules are only fired after recipients have been identified

So, if an email comes in for a recipient who doesn't exist, then the transport agent won't even get around to firing its rule.

(Well, I've not been able to get this solution to work).

Comment: Brain give solution that I can use on Exchange Server - I suppose. But on O365 it's dosen't work - youi have right.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825003/catch-all-rule-how-to-catch-all-emails-that-has-been-sent-to-not-existing-emai/11872082#11872082), you'll need to create a transport rule which redirects all messages to unknown users in your domain to the catch-all mailbox.

However, you'll also need to configure the domain as an internal relay domain, as opposed to an authoritative domain; otherwise, Exchange will reject messages addressed to non-existent users before even starting to process the transport rules.

Comment: I'm curious about this. Is there any downside to changing from _authoritative_ to _internal relay_? I'm in the same position and need to run a transport rule on a RegEx'ed incoming email address, but am not sure of the implications of this change.

Comment: When a domain is configured as "internal relay", Exchange will accept messages even for non-existent recipients, on the assumption that they can be delivered to some other mail server which shares the same domain; when instead a domain is "authoritative", Exchange will generate NDRs when it can't recipients in AD.

Comment: More info (all of them) here: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb124423(v=exchg.160).aspx.

Comment: Going to "Internal Relay" gives me the ability to accept the RegEx-based addresses and process them. I was just wondering what I lost by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

There's a CatchAll Agent for Exchange (2007, 2010, 2013) available on github:
https://github.com/Pro/exchange-catchall

This one rewrites the RCPT TO so it doesn't matter if the recipient exists, the mail will be cought.

Here you can define a subdomain or also the main domain and redirect all non existing mail adresses to a specific user.